# What is this word sounding like swanyey?

Tags: word-meaning

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWYIgqMEE2o&feature=youtu.be&t=1617), the narrator is saying something like the following:

> So, to be always clean and "*swanyey*", ..."?

What does come after "clean and"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Soigné** (or is that soignée?)

> **soigné** adjective
>
> 1 : well-groomed, sleek
>
> 2 : elegantly maintained or designed
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soign%C3%A9